# Best way to pass a value to a function template

Tags: c++, templates

I am writing a function template that accepts a (const) value of the template type. Move semantics don't apply to my case. How should I pass the parameter? For a know type, the decision is roughly:

- small: by const value
- large: by const reference

But what to do for a type that is a template parameter? The best I can think of is using a template that evaluates to either `const T` or `const T &`, depending on the size of `T` compared to the size of a pointer.

```
// when no exact match: pass as a 1 byte smaller data type would be passed
template< int N, typename T >
struct _by_const { using type = _by_const< N - 1, T >::type; };

// when up to the size of a pointer: pass by value
template< typename T >
struct _by_const< 1, T > { using type = const T; };

// when larger than a pointer: pass by reference
template< typename T >
struct _by_const< 1 + sizeof( int * ), T > { using type = const T &; };

// interface: use by_const< T > when passing a T
template< typename T >
using by_const = _by_const< sizeof( T ), T >::type;
```

Usage:

```
template< typename T > void foo( by_const< T > p ){ ... }
```

How do you do this? Is there an obvious solution I missed?

Comment: whats wrong with `const T&` ?

Comment: If you were to actually try to do some test and profile your code with either approach, it's almost a certainty that you won't be able to tell the difference, and this turns out to be much ado over nothing.

Comment: put a third bullet to your list: " you don't know the size: pass by `const&`" ;)

Comment: I checked the generated code (for Cortex-M, which is my main target) and the code size differes significantly, and (as I expected) the optimum depends on the size.

Comment: Always passing by const& is sub-optimal for small things.

Comment: btw "best way" is opinion-based. you could fix that by defining what is "best".

Comment: For me best is small code and/or fast code (which in this case is likely the same). I am open to other (relevant) definitions.

Comment: `std::is_fundamental_v<T> == true` ? by value. Otherwise by const reference. Or maybe: ever as const reference.

Comment: Do you think that passing an argument _smaller-than-pointer_ by value will be faster than passing by reference? Small arguments are typically passed in registers, so there should be no difference whether that register is set outside or inside of the function.

Comment: for me best is what works in 99% of all cases with minimum effort. I am not saying that such optimization is completely useless (in fact I dont know), but in general I wouldn't bother

Comment: Given that your compiler was told that it's a reference to a `const`, your compiler can easily optimize away the reference, and the practical difference between passing by reference, and not, will be a few CPU cycles total. And, given the largely pipelined architecture of modern multiGhz CPU, it will not actually make any difference, whatsoever. As I said: much ado over nothing.

Comment: On a cortex-M a double is larger than a pointer, so it should be passed by reference, not by value. For a realy small target (for instnace AVR8) the difference is more extreme.

Comment: @Sam my main targets are micro-controllers, not typical dekstop CPUs. This is an assue that applies to quite a few places the library I am writing, so for me it is worth the trouble.

Comment: BTW, why that recursion? You can just have two `_by_const` specialized for `true` and `false` arguments and pass `sizeof(T) > sizeof(void*)` from `by_const`. Even better, use `std::conditional_t<sizeof(T) > sizeof(void*), const T&, const T>`.

Comment: i think understand you, but still your question asks "How do you do it?" when you rather want to know "How to do it when constraits are XY and I am aiming for XYZ?"

Comment: In that case, it will probably be faster you to profile things either way, and see which one works out better. That's going to lead to faster results than a long, theoretical discussion on stackoverflow.com. There is no single answer here that is true for every operating system, every C++ compiler, every CPU that's in use in the world today. You need to profile things on your own platform.

Comment: On x86-32, a double is larger than a pointer but should be passed by value (which would use a floating point register) in the unlikely case that this has a noticeable effect on performance.

Comment: @Daniel: thanks, that simplifies things!

Comment: This is [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What are you trying to achieve? Please provide (in question) a use cases and rationale. I got feeling that there is ready simple solution for your actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if size matters,

```cpp
template<class T> using arg_t = std::conditional_t<(sizeof(T) > sizeof(int *)), T const &, T>;
```

But remember that size alone is not very important here. STL's containers may be very small on their own, as objects, (a pointer to a buffer, plus its size, for instance) but they handle huge resources on heap, that's what makes them so uncopyable. You should add something like std::is_trivial to your predicate, for better confidence.

Comment: Thanks, that makes it shorter, but it is essentially the same mechanism for deciding. PS in my context, there is no heap, so that complication doen't apply, but the constraint of being copyable is still applicable.